# Sort Pandas Dataframe on two columns with one column values repeating in sequence

Tags: python, pandas

My input dataframe have two columns:

```
df

  c1  c2
0  a   8
1  a   3
2  b   2
3  c   1
4  b  10
5  c   8
6  a  10
7  c   7
```

I want to sort the above dataframe so that the values in column 'c1' appears in sequence (abcabcac) and their corresponding column 'c2' values in ascending (or descending) order as shown below:

```
df_out:
  c1  c2
0  a   3
1  b   2
2  c   1
3  a   8
4  b  10
5  c   7
6  a  10
7  c   8
```

Please suggest how to implement such sequencing/ sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.assign(c3 = df.groupby('c1')['c2'].rank()).sort_values(['c3', 'c1']).drop('c3', axis=1)
Out[21]: 
  c1  c2
1  a   3
2  b   2
3  c   1
0  a   8
4  b  10
7  c   7
6  a  10
5  c   8
```

This creates a new column `c3` that has the rank of each letter (with respect to c2) to use in sort. Then, it is sorted by that column and `c1`. Lastly, that auxiliary column is dropped.

Comment: The ordering of `a`-`b`-`c` breaks if some letter has a duplicate value in column `c2`. For example: `df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'c2': [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6]})`

Comment: @VladimirFokow That's due to the default behaviour of `groupby.rank` (it takes the averages of the ranks). If you want it to rank them by order of appearance you can pass `method='first'` so they would have distinct ranks and you would get `a`, `b`, `c` ordered correctly:  `df.assign(c3=df.groupby('c1')['c2'].rank(method='first')).sort_values(['c3', 'c1']).drop('c3', axis=1)`

Comment: Great! Now it works as intended. Thanks!