# Swap rows postion with pandas with duplicated DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column that has duplicates and I need to swap a position between as you see in my Dataframe the Position of 'Precondition' and the 'Test Case'.

What i want to do is to reorder the rows so the Column 'Type' gets 'Test Case', 'Precondition' and then 'Test Step'

I used the `.copy()` method but it deletes all the values in the rows
[image]

And here ist the Desiered Output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoNHK.png)

Comment: we cannot see what you need to swap with what.  Please enlighten us to this...

Comment: If I rephase could it be *for each ID value, swap `Test Step`, `Test Case`*? Can you give an example of the result *after swapping*?

Comment: i added the desired output image!!

Comment: As I understood, the goal is: "Reorder the rows so that `Type` always repeats in this sequence: `Case`-`Precondition`-`Step`"

Comment: @VladimirFokow, yes thats right the order should be like you said !

Comment: Should it be "TS3" on row 8 in the desired output? also, row 17 should have "TS6"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the priorities of your values (the sequence in which they should appear).

The code creates 2 temporary columns to sort by them both, after that drops them:

```py
priorities = {'Test Case': 1, 'Precondition': 2, 'Test Step': 3}

df.assign(order = df.groupby('Type').cumcount(), 
          priorities = df['Type'].replace(priorities)
          ).sort_values(['order', 'priorities']).drop(columns=['order', 'priorities'])
```

Reference: [Sort Pandas Dataframe on two columns with one column values repeating in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38172474/14627505)